# Search recursively and delete files that start with hex 00 00 FF FF in Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, hexadecimal

Objective:

Search a folder and all subfolders for files (example: *.dat) that starts with hex sequence 00 00 FF FF on the very first 4 bytes and delete all matching files without prompting for confirmation on every file delete

For example:

In linux I was thinking a combined grep + find + hexdump + rm

for example:

rm -r delete matched files recursively

hexdump -n4 *.dat  to extract first 4 bytes of the file

grep '\x00\x00\xFF\xFF' *.dat  to find files that match returned hexdump 00 00 FF FF

**--IMPORTANT-- check if there is hex 00 00 FF FF only at the very first 4 bytes!**

**It does not matter if there is 00 00 FF FF or not anywhere else on the file! (only need to check first 4 bytes)**

Also, remember that it must scan all *.dat files in the current folder and all it's subfolders

And 00 00 FF FF must be in this exact sequence

Best solution if this was possible on Windows (even if required using third party utilities). But would be glad for a solution that runs on linux

I tried the following command, but it just returns nothing and I'm sure that there are *.dat files that start with 0000FFFF

rm -r | grep '\x00\x00\xFF\xFF' | hexdump -n4 *.dat

I can't figure out how to pipe all the required commands.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'hexdump -n4 $1 | grep -q "^0000000 0000 ffff"' Anything {} \; -delete;
```

In slo-mo:

- `find . -type f` will search all plain files under the current directory
- On each of these files, it will execute the one-line bash command `hexdump -n4 $1 | grep -q "^0000000 0000 ffff"` that returns 0 if the file starts with `00 00 FF FF`
- `find` skips to the next file if the command started with `-exec` doesn't return with rc=0, otherwise it continues executing filters or actions agsint that file, the next one being the `-delete` which is executed only if the previous filter didn't fail.

You can use this to try the technique without deleting files and display their names instead:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'hexdump -n4 $1 | grep -q "^0000000 0000 ffff"' Anything {} \; -exec printf "Would delete: %s\n" {} \;
```